# Rails, missing /app/assets/javascripts directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails beginner here !

I'm trying to load .js files through the asset pipeline. As mentioned in [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization):

> **2.2.1 Search Paths**
>
> When a file is referenced from a manifest or a helper, Sprockets searches the three default asset locations for it.
>
> The default locations are: the `images`, `javascripts` and `stylesheets` directories under the `app/assets`

Whenever I run `rails new my_project`, **Rails doesn't generate the `app/assets/javascripts` directory**, nor the related manifesto:

```
app/assets/
├── config
│   └── manifest.js
├── images
└── stylesheets
    └── application.css
```

I've manually added the `/app/assets/javascripts` directory and the `application.js` file. Here is its content:

```
//= require mytheme/js/test    # a simple alert('test')
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require mytheme/js/file1   # for each file of my theme
```

but no alert pops up.
However, using the 'Network' tab of the browser's Inspect Mode shows me that there's a .js file (nothing related to my theme though).

Should I conclude that Rails is using another manifesto to load .js files ?
Pragmatically, how could I ask the Asset Pipeline to load specific .js files ?

Long post of a beginner question, thanks for your time.

---

**NOTE:** Path should be ok, as my css is using the same path and is loading. I've also added `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor')` to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: Are you on Rails 6?

Comment: Yes. I'm reading the Release Notes, I'm sure you've already solved my problem

Comment: "Make Webpacker the default JavaScript compiler for Rails 6. (Pull Request)". Thanks for you great question, I'll find some doc online.

Comment: You can always just create the directory and link to it like in previous rails versions.  But in Rails 6 you won't get this unless you make it because of webpacker.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: Yes I did, there's lot of documentation and articles on the subject (I've to learn more about it though). I've use yarn and require the files in app/javascript/packs/application.js

Answer (score 2):

You likely have the default `javascript_pack_tag` in your application layout, which is the new default in Rails 6 with webpacker.

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

In order to use the js you have added you need the `javascript_include_tag`  tag. Like in previous versions of Rails.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

That should load those js files.